# npm publish - removing scripts from package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-publish

Before publishing my script, I have a number of scripts under the package.json to compile coffeescript, typescript and developer only commands - which make no sense once it's published.

I was wondering if there is a procedure for removing certain scripts under the package.json ? Considering that when publishing your package, it also publishes package.json.

Would this be possible to kind of remove scripts before publishing the package?

Once I publish my script, I remove a lot of the typescript and coffeescript source files (as they have been compiled), so a script I have for building no makes no sense for the published package.

Is this feasible? Or should I be thinking about another way?

Answer (score 14):

#### Short answer.

> *"Would this be possible to kind of remove scripts before publishing the package ?"*

npm does not include a built-in feature to remove scripts from `package.json`.

---

#### Long answer with solution.

> *"Is this feasible? Or should I be thinking about another way ?"*

There are a couple of built-in features known as [Pre and Post hooks](http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html) which can be utilized to meet your requirement, albeit in a rather custom way. The pertinent hooks are `prepublish` and `postpublish` and are described in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as follows;

> **prepublish**: Run BEFORE the package is packed and published, as well as on local `npm install` without any arguments...
>
> **postpublish**: Run AFTER the package is published.

A synopsis of the solution is:

1. Utilize a `prepublish` script in your projects `package.json` to invoke a custom *nodejs* script. This *nodejs* script performs the following:

   - Reads the original `package.json` data and caches it.
   - Removes specific scripts/keys from the `scripts` section of `package.json`.
   - Writes the revised data back to the original `package.json`.
2. Utilize a `postpublish` script in your projects `package.json` to invoke another custom *nodejs* script. This secondary *nodejs* script performs the following:

   - Reverts the content of `package.json` back to it's original state.

---

#### Code examples/gists.

1. The following *nodejs* script will carry out the tasks mentioned in point one above. Let's name it `cleanse-pkg.js`.

   ***cleanse-pkg.js***

   ```js
   const fs = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');

   // Define absolute paths for original pkg and temporary pkg.
   const ORIG_PKG_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../package.json');
   const CACHED_PKG_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../cached-package.json');

   // Obtain original `package.json` contents.
   const pkgData = require(ORIG_PKG_PATH);

   if (process.argv.length <= 2) {
     throw new Error('Missing npm scripts key/name argument(s)');
   }

   // Get list of arguments passed to script.
   const scriptsToRemove = process.argv[2].split(',');
   const devDepsToRemove = process.argv[3] ? process.argv[3].split(',') : [];

   // Write/cache the original `package.json` data to `cached-package.json` file.
   fs.writeFile(CACHED_PKG_PATH, JSON.stringify(pkgData), function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
   });

   // Remove the specified named scripts from the scripts section.
   scriptsToRemove.forEach(function (scriptName) {
     delete pkgData.scripts[scriptName];
   });

   // Remove the specified named pkgs from the devDependencies section.
   devDepsToRemove.forEach(function (pkgName) {
     delete pkgData.devDependencies[pkgName];
   });

   // Overwrite original `package.json` with new data (i.e. minus the specific data).
   fs.writeFile(ORIG_PKG_PATH, JSON.stringify(pkgData, null, 2), function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
   });
   ```
2. The following secondary *nodejs* script will carry out the task mentioned in point two above. Let's name this one `restore-pkg.js`.

   ***restore-pkg.js***

   ```js
   const fs = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');

   // Define absolute paths for original pkg and temporary pkg.
   const ORIG_PKG_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../package.json');
   const CACHED_PKG_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../cached-package.json');

   // Obtain original/cached contents from `cached-package.json`.
   const pkgData = JSON.stringify(require(CACHED_PKG_PATH), null, 2) + '\n';

   // Write data from `cached-package.json` back to original `package.json`.
   fs.writeFile(ORIG_PKG_PATH, pkgData, function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
   });

   // Delete the temporary `cached-package.json` file.
   fs.unlink(CACHED_PKG_PATH, function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
   });
   ```

---

#### Implementation and Usage.

1. The `prepublish` and `postpublish` scripts are defined in the projects `package.json` as follows:

   ***Contrived original package.json***

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "keep": ... ,
       "a": ... ,
       "b": ... ,
       "prepublish": "node .scripts/cleanse-pkg \"a,b,prepublish,postpublish\"",
       "postpublish": "node .scripts/restore-pkg"
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

   - Note the `\"a,b,prepublish,postpublish\"` part in the `prepublish` script. This defines the argument to pass to `cleanse-pkg.js` (i.e. it lists the names of each script to be removed before publishing). Each named script to be removed must be; provided as a single string, be separated with commas, and must not include spaces.
   - Both `cleanse-pkg.js` and `restore-pkg.js` reside in a hidden folder named `.scripts`, which itself resides at the top level of the projects directory, (i.e. at the same level as the projects `package.json`). Both *nodejs* scripts can be relocated as preferred, and the paths to them redefined as necessary in the respective *npm-script* .
2. Given the contrived `package.json` above, the actual `package.json` contents in the resultant published tarball will be as follows:

   ***Resultant/published package.json***

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "keep": ...
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

---

#### Packages in the devDependencies section.

Maybe there are packages listed in the `devDependencies` section of your projects `package.json` that you also want removed in the published `package.json`.

*(Note: Any packages listed in the [devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies) section are not downloaded when the user installs via the npm-registry though)*.

However, perhaps you'd like to remove them anyway. If that's a requirement, then `cleanse-pkg.js` also accepts an optional second argument. This argument is analogous to the first argument, whereby each named package to be removed from the `devDependencies` section must be; provided as a single string, be separated with commas, and must not include spaces.

1. Let's assume the original `package.json` is as follows this time:

   ***Contrived original package.json***

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "keep": ... ,
       "a": ... ,
       "b": ... ,
       "prepublish": "node .scripts/cleanse-pkg \"a,b,prepublish,postpublish\" \"x,z\"",
       "postpublish": "node .scripts/restore-pkg"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "x": "^1.0.2",
       "y": "^0.8.1",
       "z": "^0.8.1"
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

   - Note the additional second `\"x,z\"` argument added to the `prepublish` script to specify which packages to omit from the `devDependecies` section.
2. This time, given the contrived `package.json` above, the actual `package.json` contents in the resultant published tarball will be as follows:

   ***Resultant/published package.json***

   ```json
   {
     ...
     "scripts": {
       "keep": ...
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "y": "^0.8.1"
     },
     ...
   }
   ```

---

#### Running

This solution assumes [npm publish](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish) will be run utlizing one of the following methods:

1. From within the project directory without any argument(s). E.g. `npm publish`.
2. Specifying a the path to your projects `package.json`. E.g. `npm publish path/to/package.json`.

This will not work by providing a url or file path to a gzipped tar archive containing a single folder with a `package.json` file inside.

---

#### Additional Notes

1. To prevent both utility *nodejs* scripts, (`cleanse-pkg.js` and `restore-pkg.js`), from being published they should be added to your projects [.npmignore](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) file. Given the location of both these files explained above you can add a `.scripts` entry in `.npmignore`.
2. Both utility *nodejs* scripts, `cleanse-pkg.js` and `restore-pkg.js`, define:

   - An absolute path to the original `package.json` file.
   - An absolute path to where the temporary `cached-package.json` file should be written. Currently this is saved one-level-up/outside from the project directory to avoid it being published).

   If you choose to store `cleanse-pkg.js` and `restore-pkg.js` to a different location than the one described above, the paths in following code snippet will need to redefined as necessary in both files.

   ```js
   const ORIG_PKG_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../package.json');
   const CACHED_PKG_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../cached-package.json');
   ```

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the script `postpublish` not run at all since it is removed from the package.json scripts during `prepublish`?

Comment: @MateiRadu - Good question. At time of posting answer _pkg.json_ was read once and `pre` and `postpublish` scripts were cached early, i.e. before `prepublish` and `publish` were run. However looking at [this commit](https://github.com/npm/cli/commit/674004c4c5ef50ed303add582351b32e2293b78e#diff-6) (which is more recent that posting), my suspicion is that _"may"_ no longer be the case. npm seems to now be reading _pkg.json_ at every step of _publish_ process. Try running `npm publish --dry-run`, (i.e include `--dry-run` options) and check results. Would be great if you confirm here in comments.

Comment: I can confirm that for each hook package.json is read again so this approach no longer works. For now, my only solution is to use `npm pack` to create the tarball and a `postpack` script that edits the package.json inside the created tarball so that the origianl pkg is not altered.

Comment: don't know if it might help but this is my current [postpack](https://github.com/matt-block/react-native-in-app-browser/blob/master/scripts/postpack.ts) script.

Answer (score 11):

As of `npm@7`, the command npm-pkg can perform a delete of keys from `package.json` and does not need any external package to download or execute.

```sh
# entire scripts dictionary
$ npm pkg delete scripts

# delete specific script using the subkey syntax
$ npm pkg delete scripts.build
```

The documentation for the command is:  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-pkg

If you want a backup, then `clean-package` can provide this automatic backup, or just do it manually with:

```sh
$ cp package.json package.json.bkup
```

Comment: Best / most relevant and modern solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You might consider this package as well. https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-publish

Specifically, they provide a tool for working only with the `packakge.json`.

> ```
> $ npm run clear-package-json package.json -o package/package.json --fields scripts name
> # or
> $ npm run clear-package-json package.json > package/package.json
> # or
> $ cat package.json | npm run clear-package-json
> # `fields` also will be getted from config file
> ```

It seems to do exactly what you're requesting, but also a lot more. It does seem highly configurable.

---

**Update**

Here's a package I've created which does what you're requesting, but in a significantly different manner.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-package

```
$ clean-package --remove scripts
```