# How can I run publish without triggering postpublish afterwards?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I have a project that defines a `postpublish` action in its `package.json`.
I now have a use case where I want to execute `publish` without executing the `postpublish` action.

Is there a reliable way I can execute the `publish` action completely, so it does not trigger the `postpublish` action?

Answer (score 0):

The `--dry-run` flag works for [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) and also for `npm publish` & `npm pack` [if the CLI version is at npm@6.0.0](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/173240511455/the-new-npm-cli-a-year-in-review-or-what-you)

If you cannot operate NPM at v6, the tool *"Irish Pub"* might be exactly what you're looking for to do an npm publish dry run: https://www.npmjs.com/package/irish-pub

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for. I would like to execute the `publish` goal completely, but not to trigger the post hock `postpublish`

Comment: Precisely what you want to do (actually run publish but not the postpublish "hook") is not possible from any conventional uses of npm. I'm curious about your use-case/requirements for this behavior, but if it must be done see here for a discussion about modifying the package.json itself when running script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48823116/3191929